# Error, Opportunity String Id too long!

Tags: integration, opportunity, salesforce-id, npsp, nonprofit-starter-pack

Using the NPSP.
When i submit a donation from a web form to salesforce using a click and pledge integrated platform; it creates a correct account and contact but gives me error on the opportunity record creation.
[image: String too long ErrMssg]

Guess Salesforce concatenates to the click and pledge id his own generated id. 
How can i overcome this error? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to specify a UUID (unique 36 character string) where you should specify a Salesforce Id (18 characters built in a very particular manner).

Comment: I can't view the image, but if you need to store an ID from an external system, make a text field on the object which has the "External ID" property checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forum post [Error on Connect Form to Salesforce](https://forums.clickandpledge.com/forum/platform-product-forums/connect-peer-to-peer-fundraising-platform/28996-error-on-connect-form-to-salesforce) seems to cover your problem:

> We are rolling out the new Connect form, but are getting an error in Salesforce:
>
> Code:
> `Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STRING_TOO_LONG, WID: data value too large: 87b3511b-fbe1-4d03-bda6-6450a1440765`

Response:

> The error you are seeing is due to the instance being on an old release. The new forms use a 64 character WID and the old release had only 18 character limit on WID.
>
> We need to update all your clients as soon as possible.
>
> Please see the release note: [Salesforce PaaS 9.7010: Compatibility Release for Connect 2](https://forums.clickandpledge.com/forum/news-announcements-release-notes/news-announcements/27260-salesforce-paas-9-7010-compatibility-release-for-connect-2)

From the release notes:

> WID field length increased to 40 characters for Connect 2.x forms WID.

It appears to be a mismatch between the field length in Salesforce and what the external component is expecting.